# Why does `systemctl enable rpcbind' change the volume of my sound? And how do I prevent this?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, alsa, pulseaudio

I just did:

```
$ systemctl enable rpcbind
```

And this caused the volume on my headphones to increase *severly*.

First off, I don't understand *why* this happens, as rpcbind seems completely unrelated to my sound? Issuing the command a second time doesn't change the sound, and neither does `start rpcbind`.

Secondly, I would like to *prevent* this from happening again; the volume jumped more than a little bit (some panicky actions to remove my headphones accompanied by a loud expletive followed).

This is not the first time I've noticed that systemd commands change my volume by the way... I was playing a HTML5 `<audio>` tag in Firefox through pulseaudio. I'm running Arch Linux (updated).

Comment: The bug has been fixed in commit [6e392c9c45643d106673c6643ac8bf4e65da13c1](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/commit/?id=6e392c9c45643d106673c6643ac8bf4e65da13c1) and will be a part of systemd 220 unless backported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88401).

The actual root cause is somewhat deeper: systemd's reload logic is flawed. That's why you saw it only when you had *actually* enabled a unit (i. e. a "disabled -> enabled" transition had taken place): in this case systemd implicitly reloads the units.

I'm working on fixing the bug; in the meantime, if *this manifestation* (spontaneous volume change) bothers you, you can work around it by using `alsa-state.service` instead of `alsa-{,re}store.service`. Refer to manuals or unit files themselves for details on how to use the former instead of the latter.

## UPDATE

The bug has been fixed in commit [6e392c9c45643d106673c6643ac8bf4e65da13c1](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/commit/?id=6e392c9c45643d106673c6643ac8bf4e65da13c1) and will be a part of systemd 220 (unless backported).